# Save system not opening fstream files?

Tags: c++, save, fstream

I am working on a save file system for a game, and trying to make sure I can get the file open in a small test program, determine whether it is empty, if it is empty prompt the user to create a character, and if its not empty load the character's information into variables to be used for the game.  So far in my testing I've created the files in notepad (leaving them empty), saved them with appropriate extensions, and attempted to open the file and test if they are empty.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main ( int argc, char* argv[])
{
   struct charFile
   {
      int chapterNum;
      int savePoint;
      string firstName;
      char gender, hairColor, hairType, hairLength, eyeColor, profession, magic, martialSkills;
      bool hasPet;
   } character;

   fstream save;

   char saveFileChoice;
   string saveFile;

   cout << "Select a File (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6): ";
   cin >> saveFileChoice;


   saveFile = saveFileChoice + ".charsav";

   save.open(saveFile.c_str());
   if (!save.good())
   {
      cout << "Save file cannot be opened.\n";
   }

   char tempStr[12];
   save.getline (tempStr, 256);
   if ( tempStr == "EMPTY" )
   {
      cout << "There is no save data in the file.  Starting a new game...\n\n";
      cout << "What is your character's name? ";
      cin >> character.firstName;
      save << character.firstName;

   }

return 0;
}
```

I was wondering why the file was never dropping into the if statement even though it was empty, and then even when I added EMPTY ascii characters to the file and changed the condition.  Then I put in:

```
if (!save.good())
       {
          cout << "Save file cannot be opened.\n";
       }
```

and on running it constantly displays the message so for some reason the file isn't opening.  =/ I can't figure out why though.

I've checked the files and they are not being formatted as .charsav.txt or anything, they are still just 1.charsav, 2.charsav, etc.  I feel like I'm missing something easy and obvious.  Can anybody point it out for me?

Comment: The string handling should be: `std::string tempStr; std::getline(save, tempStr);`. But you're still forgetting a ton of error checking left, right and centre.

Comment: Do you have permissions to write into the working directory?

Comment: @KerrekSB Yes there's a lot of errors I will be checking eventually, making sure the user is entering the right kind of character and not a value other than 1-6, etc etc.  For now when I knew what input had to be I've left that sort of thing off.  I'll try those std::string operations but I'm not sure how effective they'll be if the fstream is failing, if it refuses to open the file I could getline from it till the cows come home, as it were, and...whether I wrote getline right or not it would still be falling out of the if statement since it won't work while the fstream is in fail state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if (!strcmp(tempStr, "EMPTY" )) is how you compare strings

Comment: Um...well thank you, I will use that.  Although the other works for my purposes temporarily, as it did for the madlib file we did in class.

I'm still having the fstream fail to open, though, so it doesn't even get anything in tempStr to compare with anyways, because the fstream isn't open?

Comment: There are some other methods of fstream you can experiment with, .eof() and .is_open()

Comment: adding the following tests: 'save.open(saveFile.c_str());
   if (!save.good())
   {
      cout << "Save file cannot be opened.\n";
   }
   if (save.fail())
      cout << "Save file failed." << endl;
   if (save.bad())
      cout << "Save file is bad." << endl;
   if (save.is_open())' and it displays the failed error message so fstream is failing.  At least its not .bad()! haha! Still curious why though.  Wonder if its how I concatenate the filename from the user selection? =?

Comment: I would have used saveFile = saveFileChoice; savefile += ".charsav";

Comment: Another thing worth noting, when you fail to open a file you print a message, but you should really have an else after that so that the code that handles the opened file will not run in case of failure

Comment: HAH!  That's it.  =P I'll have to figure out why that particular concatenation screws up saveFile's value, but its opening the stream and comparing the contents appropriately now by separating the two statements as you suggested.  Odd, but its working now.  Thank you!